# Speed up 6,000 row query with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I have a query that returns roughly 6,000 results. Although this query executes in under a second in MySQL, once it is run through Zend Framework 2, it experiences a significant slowdown.

For this reason, I tried to do it a more "raw" way with PDO:

```
class ThingTable implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
        // ...

        public function goFast()
        {


            $db_config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['db'];
            $pdo = new PDO($db_config['dsn'], $db_config['username'], $db_config['password']);

            $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT objectNumber, thingID, thingmaker, hidden, title FROM Things ', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS, PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            $statement->execute();

            return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        }
}
```

This doesn't seem to have much of a speedup, though.

I think the problem might be that Zend is still trying to create a new `Thing` object for each record, even though it is only a partial list of columns. I'd really be okay not populating any objects. I really just need a few columns with those attributes to iterate over.

As suggested by user [MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191572/monkeyzeus), the following was used for bench-marking:

```
$start = microtime(true);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo (microtime(true) - $start).' seconds';
```

And in response:

> In a VM, that returns 0.0050520896911621. This is in line with what it
>   is when I just run the command straight in MySQL. I believe the
>   overhead is in Zend, but not sure how to quite go about that. Again if
>   I had to guess, I'd say it is because Zend is adding overhead while
>   trying to be nice with the results, but I'm not quite sure how to
>   proceed after that.
>
> [I'm] not so worried about the query. It is a single select statement.
>   `goFast()` gets called by the Zend `indexAction()` --similar to other
>   actions used across the project--this one is just way slower at
>   returning the page. One problem I found was that Zend's `$this->url()`
>   was slowing things down a bit. So I removed those, but the performance
>   still isn't great.

How can I speed this up?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is network latency. Is MySQL server running remotely or in localhost?

Comment: Test your query by itself, create a stand alone script, put your query in it and run it, also try switching to MySQLi temporarily and see if you experience the same speeds, if you do, you'll know it's not the framework. [@]MonkeyZeus Stop what ? writing two comments suggesting how to troubleshoot a problem? ...well, I think that's better than writing a comment just to tell someone else to stop trying to help someone else. There, I hope you're happy now.

Comment: @angelcool.net very, thank you

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You're welcome. Btw I did not know it was the hijacking thing that bothered you so much.

Comment: lol , so you edited question with my suggestion and down voted my answer ?

Comment: Is there a possibility that Zend creates new instance of object, somewhere in the loop? This might be quite slow. If you still need to create new object (or a set of objects) for lets say each DB row, then do clone instead of new Class(); clone is much faster. Check Zend internals

Answer (score 1):

When you say , that query runs under a second in MySQL , what do you mean ? did you try to run this query and print ALL 6000 rows ? or you just queried this and command line printed first/last few of them ?

The problem might be that , you are fetching them all , going through cursor , you are copying all the data ( 6000 rows ) from MySQL to PHP and then returning it , are you sure you want to do this ?

Maybe you could return a statement/cursor to the Query and then iterate through rows when you really need it ?

Your problem is not the SQL itself , but fetching them into PHP array all at once.

You can test it by logging the time it needs to actually execute SQL and fetching it into PHP array.

Do not use fetchall , return the statement itself and in the function/code where you have to run "foreach" this array , use statement to fetch each row one by one.

Comment: It is downvoted because many users very naively apply "rules" for voting on this site.

Comment: @ogres I think the (lack of) formatting scared someone.  Or they just really thought your answer wasn't helpful.  Your answer is a bit shotgun-y, and it's hard to tell which parts of the post are for clarification and which are actually a potential solution.  I suggested that you [edit] your post.